# When running `rm -rf`, is it possible to exclude certain subdirectories?

Tags: bash, mount, disk-cleanup, exclude, recursion

I routinely use bind mounts to aid in making space available in multiple locations without having to have multiple logical volumes / physical partitions / LUNs, etc.

For example, I may have a 200G LV mounted at `/space`. From there, I will make subdirectories like `var_opt` and `var_log` which I can then bind mount to `/var/opt` and `/var/log`, respectively.

When doing a cleanup on the 'space' directory, is it possible to *exclude* directories from an `rm -rf` running inside `/space`?

Example:

```
# pwd
/space
# rm -rf * {except-for-var_opt-and-var_log}
```

Is there a different or better (but similarly simple) way to accomplish what I'm trying to do that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with find + xargs + rm combination?

`find /space ! -iregex '(var_opt|var_log)' | xargs rm -f`

or something in that tune. Of course, it might be wise to first instruct xargs execute something more harmless, such as echo, before changing it to rm ...

Comment: didn't think of that! good idea :)

Comment: **Do not use xargs** (except with `-0`)! It expects input quoted in a highly peculiar way that `find` does not generate. So this command will fail horribly if there are file names containing spaces or `\'"`. Instead, use `-exec`: find /space ! -iregex '(var_opt|var_log)' -exec rm {} +`. Or since `-iregex` is specific to GNU find anyway, use its `-delete` action: `find /space ! -iregex '(var_opt|var_log)' -delete`.

Comment: You can also use the `-not -path` flags as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460641/1524502. This proved a little more robust for me.

Answer (score 18):

Simple conceptually, and has a low risk of error:

```
mkdir TO_DELETE
mv * TO_DELETE
mv TO_DELETE/var_opt TO_DELETE/var_log .
rm -rf TO_DELETE
```

Ignore the error from `mv` about moving `TO_DELETE` to a subdirectory of itself.

You can also use ksh's extended globs:

```
rm -rf !(var_opt|var_log)
```

These are also available in bash if you enable them:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf !(var_opt|var_log)
```

Ditto in zsh:

```
setopt ksh_glob
rm -rf !(var_opt|var_log)
```

Zsh also has its own extended globs:

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -rf ^var_(opt|log)
```

Comment: That doesn't help *at all* if the directories are actively bind-mounted

Comment: should `TO_DELETE` be on different than the files/folders's parent folder?

Comment: @alper No. That would increase the risk of a typo and wouldn't work if the directory is a mount point.

Comment: @warren How do bind mounts affect either of the methods in my answer?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - if you've bind-mounted something, you can end up deleting it out from under yourself by deleting in the "original" (or bound) location, and it disappearing in the other. That *may* be expected behavior, but all too often, I've found, it's a surprise. Plus, you cannot *move* a bind mounted directory elsewhere :)

Comment: @warren You can move a directory that's bind-mounted elsewhere. You can't move a mount point. But in any case you wouldn't end up deleting `var_opt` and `var_log`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - that's gotta be a recent change - any time I tried to move a bind-mounted base directory, it's promptly broken whatever was access the other location (through at least RHEL 7)

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

Check the output of

```
env ls -d -1 space/* | grep -E -v 'var_opt|var_log'
```

If that looks like the list of files/folders you want to delete, use

```
env ls -d -1 space/* | grep -E -v 'var_opt|var_log' | xargs rm -rf
```

I suggest use of `env ls` instead of `ls` to disable any aliasing of `ls` in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

If your input file names are generated by users, you need to deal with
surprising file names containing space, ', or " in the filename.

The use of `xargs` can lead to nasty surprises because of [the separator problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Separator_problem).

[GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) does not have that problem.

```
find /space ! -iregex '(var_opt|var_log)' | parallel -X rm -f
```

Watch the [intro video for GNU Parallel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

If the directories you want to preserve are exactly the mountpoints, you might be able to use `--one-file-system` in GNU `rm`.

I haven't investigated how this is implemented, but I'm guessing that this won't do what you want if the bind mount is from within the same filesystem, so be careful!  `rm` doesn't have a `--no-act` option, but you can pipe `yes no | rm -ir .` for example.